# Flutter: While creating new emulator , it is showing error as No device definitions are available, Why so?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create new emulator but unable to create it in Visual Studio code. It is showing 'No device definitions are available.'

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on which OS you are working, from windows you should be able to create one like this:

```
cd C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
avdmanager create avd -n "FlutterEmulator" -k "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86" -d "Nexus 5"
```

In case the image is not available, it's possible to download it with:

```
sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86"
```